# Lost "click" event during AJAX refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, events

```js
$(":input").on("change", function(e) {
  console.log("change triggered");
 $("#section").html("<button id='order'>Order</button>");
  registerButtons();
});

function registerButtons() {
  $("#order").on("click", function(e) {
    console.log("click triggered");
   alert("Hello World");
  });
  $("#order").on("mousedown mouseup", function(e) {
    console.log(e.type + " triggered");
  });
}

registerButtons();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="123"/>
<div id="section">
  <button id="order">Order</button>
</div>
```

I have a web page with a button and some input fields.

- On the button an **click** event is registered
- On the input fields an **change** event is registered

The **onChange** will trigger an AJAX server call, and the result will replace parts of the web page - including the button. After AJAX result is processed, all listener are registered again.

Now the problem. A user changes the value of an input field, and clicks directly the button - but to slow (lets assume the user needs 500ms for the click), so the **onChange** event is fired and the page is "updated/replaced". Now the "old" button fires an **onMouseDown** and the "new" button fires an **onMouseUp** event - but no **onClick**.

My current workaround is, to register the two **mouseDown**/**mouseUp** events, get the timestamp of the mouse down, and if the mouse up comes in 2 seconds, do what should be done by the **onClick**.
It is no option to remove the button part from the AJAX response - in worst case the button could be removed and replaced by an user info.

My hope is, that there is a better solution... any ideas?

Comment: Disable the button on the click (maybe displaying a loading animation). So the user can only click on it again after it is replaced via ajax

Comment: The problem is, that the events are fired in parallel (**onChange** + **onMouseDown**), but the user is not fast enough - or the server/page reload to fast.

Comment: Oh sry I misread this. So when the onchange is triggering the ajax call, disable the button with this event. So the user don't has the possibility to click on the button while content is replacing.

Comment: Still a timing issue - and it is not 100% clear, which event fires first, so it could be the case that **onMouseDown** is fired before **onChange**. It is important, that the **onChange** event is always fired (a value could cause a complete change of the current page), the user doesn't really see, that the page is "refreshed". And it is also important, that the user can click the button - if no error occurs with the entered values - it is the "order" button - nobody wants to disable an "order" button ;-)

Comment: Please show us your code. Why don't you use onClick instead of onChange?

Comment: Added example code - a little bit simpler as the real code, but the function and the result is the same.

Comment: @MichaelS. Checkout my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the event delegation and set your listener on the container instead of the button.

You are adding a click listener to your old button and your adding a new button to the dom. So the click won't work.

The button wasn't working because for some reason it can't focus when you hover over it. So I added a getFocus method and now it should work.

```js
$("input").on("change", function(e) {

    console.log("change triggered");

    $("#section").html("<button id='order'>Order</button>");

});


function registerButtons() {
   
  $('#section').on("mouseup", '#order', function(e) {
       
        alert('Clicked!');
 });

}

registerButtons();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="123"/>
<div id="section">
  <button id="order">Order</button>
</div>
```

I just found out that jQuery provides a sweet API that can be used for event delegation. This way we don't have to manually check for event target. Check it out http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("input").on("change", function(e) {
  console.log("change triggered");
    $("#section").html("<button id='order'>Order</button>");
});


    function registerButtons() {
      $("#section").on("click", '#order', function(e) {
            console.log("click triggered");
            alert("Hello World");
     });

    $("#section").on('mouseover','#order', function(e){
            $(this).focus();
    });
}

registerButtons();
```

Comment: The idea looks good. If you just replace this in my short example, you will see, that won't work as expected. The "click" event won't be triggered.

Comment: From a technical perspective this would be solution - but this solution just removes the problem, that two events are fired in parallel. With the mouse over focus change, directly the **onChange** event would be fired, and then the **onClick** is no problem any more.  But as said, technical it is ok, from usability it is no solution - if the user just moves the mouse pointer out of the text field (nothing overlaying the letters inserted), and as a "mistake" the user moves the pointer to the order button - the text field will lose the focus.

Comment: @MichaelS. you are right. Check out the simplified updated answer.

Comment: The Problem is still, that this solution is not very user friendly. If I would run a usability test on that, I'm sure some of the test persons had problems, that releasing the mouse button over the button will trigger a "click". Thank you for your ideas!! It always helps, to discuss solutions, to find the hopefully perfect solution for a problem. But so far, my workaround is the only working function. Hopefully you have other good ideas!